# PHPExcel chart included imported file's output is corrupt

Tags: php, excel, charts, phpexcel

I'm a biologist and try to handle a ton of data from FlowCytometry then handling it with Excel. I have exported my files in csv then I tried to put them in a pre created Excel file with php. I figured out when I read and write exactly the same Excel file with PHPExcel PHP extension it doesn't handles my charts the output file is corrupt, and Excel prompting to fix and fixes it without the charts.

I simplified my files without any new input and produces the same results, can you help me to fix this?

My simplified code:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$txtOutputExcelName = "Histogram.xlsx";

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object from import" , EOL;

// Sample File Name that is going to be cloned
$inputFileName = './sample/Analysis_sample.xlsx';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save($txtOutputExcelName);
```

My simplified Excel file is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4860217/Analysis_sample.xlsx

Thank you for your help,
Zoltan

- Mac OS X 10.11.4
- PHP version 7.0.0
- PHPExcel 1.8.1